# JSON to pandas dataframe for multiple filepaths

Tags: python, json, pandas, json-normalize

I have a folder of 40 customer data files. Each customer has a json file filled with different purchases. An example path is ../customer_data/customer_1/transaction.json

I want to load this json file into a data frame with `customer_id`, `date`, `instore` and `rewards` columns. The customer id is the folder name and then for each set of in instore/rewards I want a new row.

GOAL: the above file should look like this:

```
   customer_id| date                     | instore          | rewards
   customer_1 |2018-12-21T12:02:42-08:00 |  0               | 0
   customer_1 |2018-12-24T06:19:03-08:00 |98.25211334228516 | 16.764389038085938
   customer_1 |2018-12-24T06:19:03-08:00 |99.88800811767578 | 18.61212158203125
```

I tried the following code but get this error ValueError: Conflicting metadata name flexion, need distinguishing prefix :

```
# path to file
p = Path('../customer_data/customer_1/transaction.json')

# read json
with p.open('r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())

# create dataframe
df = json_normalize(data, record_path='purchase', meta=['instore', 'rewards'], errors='ignore')
```

Any suggestions would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use [`rglob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rglob) to find all files.
- Fix `data` by filling the empty lists in the `purchase` key.
- Use [`parent`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parent) & [`stem`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.stem) to get the customer id from the path.

  - Given `p = Path('../customer_data/customer_1/transaction.json')`
  - `p.parent.stem` returns `'customer_1'`

```py
import pandas as pd
import json
from pathlib import Path

file_path = Path('../customer_data')
files = file_path.rglob('transaction.json')

df_list = list()
for file in files:

    # read json
    with file.open('r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        data = json.loads(f.read())
    
    # fix purchase where list is empty
    for x in data:
        if not x['purchase']:  # checks if list is empty
            x['purchase'] = [{'instore': 0, 'rewards': 0}]
        
    # create dataframe
    df = pd.json_normalize(data, 'purchase', ['date', 'tierLevel'])
    
    # add customer
    df['customer_id'] = file.parent.stem
    
    # add to dataframe list
    df_list.append(df)
    

df = pd.concat(df_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, `customer_id` wasn't in your json so I just made it up:

```
path = '../customer_data/customer_1/transaction.json'
with open('1.json', 'r+') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

df = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path=['purchase'], meta=[['date'], ['tierLevel']])
df['customer_id'] = path.split('/')[2]
print(df)


     instore    rewards                       date tierLevel customer_id
0  98.252113  16.764389  2018-12-24T06:19:03-08:00         7  customer_1
1  99.888008  18.612122  2018-12-24T06:19:03-08:00         7  customer_1
```

Comment: Thanks and the customer id is only in the file path. Is there a way I can extract it from the file path itself?

Comment: This won't get the first dictionary

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Don't think `json_normalize` supports that.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Yes is there a way to get the nulls as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can use my library anyjsontodf.py

Basically:

```
import anyjsontodf as jd

df = jd.jsontodf(jsonfile)
```

**Github**: https://github.com/fSEACHAD/anyjsontodf

**Medium article**: https://medium.com/@fernando.garcia.varela/dancing-with-the-dictionary-transforming-any-json-to-pandas-3328b49269d0

Hope this helps!